# Can I pass a number for varchar2 in Oracle? 

Tags: sql, oracle, ora-01722

I have an Oracle table and a column (`col1`) has type `varchar2(12 byte)`. It has one row and value of `col1` is `1234`

When I say

```
select * from table where col1 = 1234
```

Oracle says invalid number. Why is that?  Why I cannot pass a number when it is `varchar2`?

EDIT: All the responses are great. Thank you. But I am not able to understand why it does not take `1234` when `1234` is a valid varchar2 datatype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you expect that Oracle will implicitly cast 1234 to a character type.  To the contrary, Oracle is implicitly casting the column to a number.  There is a non-numeric value in the column, so Oracle throws an error.  The [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/sql_elements002.htm) warns against implicit casts just before it explains how they will be resolved.  The rule which explains the behaviour you're seeing is:

> When comparing a character value with a numeric value, Oracle converts the character data to a numeric value.

Comment: Thanks. so the character is 1234, which oracle is converting implicitly to a number. SO why the error since 1234 is a valid number?

Comment: Something in the table isn't a number.  Oracle leaves 1234 as a number.  It is trying to convert the value in the column to match.  When it finds a value that isn't a number, it throws the error.

Answer (score 4):

Oh, it is much better to convert to char rather than to numbers:

```
select *
from table
where col1 = to_char(1234)
```

When the col1 does not look like a number, to_number returns an error, stopping the query.

Answer (score 4):

> Oracle says invalid number. Why is that? Why I cannot pass a number when it is varchar2?

Oracle does an implicit conversion from character type of `col1` to number, since you're comparing it as a number.

Also, you assume that `1234` is the *only* row that's being fetched. In reality, Oracle has to fetch all rows from the table, and then filter out as per the `where` clause. Now there's a character value in `col1` that's being fetched before it encounters your `1234` row & that's causing the error, since the character cannot be converted to a number.

[This fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ded06/1) shows the behaviour. Since `abc` canot be converted to a number, you get that error message

---

Now if the *only* record in the table is that of col1 containing a numeric character, you'll see that the [statement will work fine](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ded06/4)